# Why can I use an Observable without subscribe?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My problem is this example https://github.com/AngularFirebase/144-firestore-group-chat from Jeff Delaney. 
I'm trying to understand why it is possible to use an observable without `subscribe()`.

For example the auth.service.ts from the Github repo:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { auth } from 'firebase/app';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import {
  AngularFirestore,
  AngularFirestoreDocument
} from '@angular/fire/firestore';

import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap, first, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AuthService {
  user$: Observable<any>;

  constructor(
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private afs: AngularFirestore,
    private router: Router
  ) {
    this.user$ = this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
      switchMap(user => {
        if (user) {
          return this.afs.doc<any>(`users/${user.uid}`).valueChanges();
        } else {
          return of(null);
        }
      })
    );
  }
```

There is no `subscribe()` in the constructor nor in the rest of the project, but the example works fine.

Another example is in chat.service.ts this function:

```
getUserChats() {
    return this.auth.user$.pipe(
      switchMap(user => {
        return this.afs
          .collection('chats', ref => ref.where('uid', '==', user.uid))
          .snapshotChanges()
          .pipe(
            map(actions => {
              return actions.map(a => {
                const data: Object = a.payload.doc.data();
                const id = a.payload.doc.id;
                return { id, ...data };
              });
            })
          );
      })
    );
  }
```

Why is it possible to use an Observable without `subscribe()`?

Comment: Maybe it gets passed to some framework code that takes an observable. Maybe there's an async pipe in a template. Give a [mcve] of your attempts to adapt this to your needs.

Comment: Basically I just want to know how it is possible in this example. That's why I posted the Github repo. There are a few places that use observables without subscribe(). And I don't understand why.

Comment: It's unreasonable to expect people to read through a bunch of code that's not even in the question. Also note that why is a different question than how.

Comment: You're right. My bad. Should I change the question or something?

Comment: You could [edit] it down to one specific query you have.

Comment: Is it better know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's `async` in this [guard](https://github.com/AngularFirebase/144-firestore-group-chat/blob/master/src/app/services/auth.guard.ts) file, that allows the app to work properly. Since the guard is asking `getUser()` method from the **AuthService** which has a `.toPromise()` at the return:

```
getUser() {
    return this.user$.pipe(first()).toPromise();
}
```

Comment: And what about the functions 'getUserChats()' and 'joinUsers()' in 'chat.service.ts'? Are they also promises because of the async call in the respective HTML files?

Comment: yes, they are being used as `async` pipe in the html files.

Comment: Know I understand. Thank you!